# Mixed Distributions - Expectation and Variance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-expectation, mixing

> A bike has probability of breaking down $p$, on any given day. The repair cost of the bike, whenever it breaks down, is distributed as a Gamma random variable with shape $\alpha$ and rate $\lambda$.
>
> 1. What is the expected repair cost, given that the bike broke down?
> 2. What is the expected annual repair cost?
> 3. What is the variance of the annual repair cost?

First, I want to define the event that the bike breaks down on a given day to be $X \sim Bern(p)$, and the repair cost (given that the bike broke down) to be $Y|X \sim Gamma(\alpha, \lambda)$.

1. $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X] = \frac{\alpha}{\lambda}$
2. $\mathbb{E}[365X \cdot \mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]] = \frac{\alpha}{\lambda} \mathbb{E}[365X] = 365 p \frac{\alpha}{\lambda}$
3. $Var(365X \cdot \mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]) = 365^2 \cdot \mathbb{E}^2[Y\mid X] \cdot Var(X) = 365^2 \cdot \frac{\alpha^2}{\lambda^2} p (1-p)$

Am I on the right track here? I am having issues understanding if I used the notation correctly, or whether I even defined my random variables correctly.

Comment: You do not have enough information to solve b) & c) - there is no time given for $p$: is it per day, per year, per lifetime of the bike?

Comment: Also, if you overcome the issue in my first comment the distribution you need is Poisson - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question. $p$ refers to the probability per day.

I'm not sure how to apply the Poisson distribution here--the repair cost itself follows another distribution, so would I not have to take that into account?

Comment: My reasoning for the expectation I have is that the bike breaks down on average $365\cdot\mathbb{E}[X] = 365p$ times in a year, and each time it does break down, the cost to repair it follows the Gamma distribution which I calculated from (1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of breakdowns per year (A [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with $\lambda=365p$) and $Y_i$ the cost of the $i$th breakdown (i.i.d [Gamma distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) with shape α and rate λ) and S = $\sum_{i=1}^XY_i$ (a sum of a random number of i.i.d random variables).

1. As you say $\mathbb E(Y_i)=\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}$

For the next 2 we are working with $S$ and we can use [these](http://www.math.unl.edu/~sdunbar1/ProbabilityTheory/Lessons/Conditionals/RandomSums/randsum.shtml) results. So,

2. $$\begin{align}\mathbb E(S)&=\mathbb E(X)\mathbb
       E(Y)\\&=365p\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}\end{align}$$.
3. $$\begin{align}Var(S)&=\mathbb E(X)Var(Y)+\mathbb E(Y)^2Var(X)\\
   &=365p\frac{\alpha}{\lambda^2}+\left(\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}\right)^2365p\\
   &=365p\frac{\alpha(1+\alpha)}{\lambda^2}
   \end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! However, isn't $(\mathbb{E}[Y])^2 = \left( \frac{\alpha}{\lambda} \right)^2$? Also, is there a reason I can't use $X \sim Bin(365, p)$? If I do so, $Var(X)$ will be different. However, I am not sure why it won't work...

Comment: Yes - this was a typo on the second last line, didn't affect the final result. Feel free to use a Binomial distribution - you will be wrong but I believe in freedom! Seriously, that is really another question - post it and I will offer a full answer.

Comment: Thanks! I've asked the follow-up question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1061916/177617).